# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb while compiling iproute2

Tags: ip, make, iproute

I am trying to compile iproute2-3-12-0 on Fedora 19, I have BerkeleyDB installed, the command `ls -la /usr/lib/libdb*` gives following results:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1847852 May 16  2013 /usr/lib/libdb-5.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      12 Sep 18 20:15 /usr/lib/libdb-5.so -> libdb-5.3.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 Jan  4 12:57 /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3 -> libdbus-1.so.3.7.4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  317720 Nov 11 19:24 /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3.7.4
```

I have newest version of Bison and Flex. I use kernel: 3.12.8-200.fc19.x86_64.
I have ldb in `/usr/lib and /usr/lib64`. I did not find any `LDFLAGS` in `Makefile` though.

I get an error:

```
ssfilter.y: conflicts: 27 shift/reduce
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [arpd] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

A closer look at the end of make log reveals:

```
        make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Traffic_Shaping/iproute2-3.12.0/bridge'
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o bridge.o bridge.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o fdb.o fdb.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o monitor.o monitor.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o link.o link.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o mdb.o mdb.c
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o vlan.o vlan.c
gcc   bridge.o fdb.o monitor.o link.o mdb.o vlan.o ../lib/libnetlink.a ../lib/libutil.a  ../lib/libnetlink.a ../lib/libutil.a -o bridge
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Traffic_Shaping/iproute2-3.12.0/bridge'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/Traffic_Shaping/iproute2-3.12.0/misc'
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o ss.o ss.c
bison ssfilter.y -o ssfilter.c
ssfilter.y: conflicts: 27 shift/reduce
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE   -c -o ssfilter.o ssfilter.c
gcc   ss.o ssfilter.o  ../lib/libnetlink.a ../lib/libutil.a -o ss
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE  -o nstat nstat.c -lm
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE  -o ifstat ifstat.c ../lib/libnetlink.a ../lib/libutil.a -lm
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE  -o rtacct rtacct.c ../lib/libnetlink.a ../lib/libutil.a -lm
gcc -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -Wold-style-definition -O2 -I../include -DRESOLVE_HOSTNAMES -DLIBDIR=\"/usr/lib64\" -DCONFDIR=\"/etc/iproute2\" -D_GNU_SOURCE -I/usr/include/libdb4  -o arpd arpd.c ../lib/libnetlink.a ../lib/libutil.a -ldb -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [arpd] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/Traffic_Shaping/iproute2-3.12.0/misc'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I get `ld` to find `libdb`?

Comment: [First Google result says](https://lists.debian.org/debian-devel/2000/10/msg00151.html): you need to have the appropriate `-dev` package for `libdb-5.3.so` installed. As I'm not using Fedora, you'll have to figure out the correct package name yourself unfortunately.

Comment: [Possibly `libdb-devel`?](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libdb-devel)

Comment: your libs are in `/usr/lib` and you compile with `/usr/lib64`, why?

Comment: @martin-von-wittich Bingo! Many thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [@bersh astutely points out in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111223/usr-bin-ld-cannot-find-ldb-while-compiling-iproute2/111230#comment172113_111223), you appear to be mixing libraries that have been compiled for different architectures (32-bit vs. 64-bit). On Fedora 32-bit libraries go in the `/usr/lib`, while 64-bit libraries go in `/usr/lib64`. You can convince yourself of this with a couple of examples.

#### Example

Let's pick on one of the share libraries for the DNS resolver, `/usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so`. We can see that it's part of a 32-bit RPM.

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so 
glibc-2.17-20.fc19.i686
```

You can also see that the library is a 32-bit ELF headered file.

```
$ file /usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so
/usr/lib/libresolv-2.17.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), BuildID[sha1]=0xeee8b9e6cb49f8dd64059cc158ce2c55f8c6df5b, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, not stripped
```

So you need to take care when compiling your software to make sure that you have the appropriate libraries in place (32 & 64) as well as the corresponding header files. On Fedora (and all Red Hat based distros) the packages are named like so:

- 32-bit - libdb-5.3.21-11.fc19.i686
- 64-bit - libdb-5.3.21-11.fc19.x86_64
- 32-bit header files - libdb-devel-5.3.21-11.fc19.i686
- 64-bit header files - libdb-devel-5.3.21-11.fc19.x86_64

#### Your library, libdb

If you notice the library file is available in both architectures. Given the output of your `kernel` package being x64, I would assume you meant to install the 64-bit versions of the libraries.

Also since you're attempting to compile you'll want to install the header files for your architecture too.

```
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib/libdb-5.3.so
libdb-5.3.21-11.fc19.i686
$ rpm -qf /usr/lib64/libdb-5.3.so
libdb-5.3.21-11.fc19.x86_64
```

#### How do I know what package to install?

If you see your compiles are calling for files that you do not have then you can use `repoquery` to find out what package(s) provide various files like so:

```
$ repoquery -f '*/libdb-5.3.so'
libdb-0:5.3.21-11.fc19.x86_64
libdb-0:5.3.21-11.fc19.i686
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining that to me! Now I can clearly see that I've been missing bits and pieces. Installation of libdb-devel did the job! Best Regards

Comment: @domaniqs - great news!

Comment: The `-devel` packages contain whatever is needed to develop against the library. This includes header (`include`) files, but also shared and static libraries for linking, and sometimes special build tools or configuration.

Answer (score 0):

`lib` will contain 32bit libraries, and `lib64` 64bit.  I would assume your `gcc` is generating 64bit binaries. So `/lib64` (`/usr/lib64`) needs to have the correct db libraries.  You can run the gcc command manually with `--verbose` to see everything it's doing. (i.e. the `ld` command it's running)